# Limit result of join query and order

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query

```
select a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.`filename`) as `filesnames`
from `school_classes` a
join classes_data.`classes_albums` b on a.`school_key` = b.`school_key`
    and a.`class_key` = b.`class_key`
group by a.`ID`
```

the result of this query is [image: image_1]

i want to add to it

> ORDER BY b.`added_date` DESC LIMIT 2

so the output of filenames column only shows latest 2 files , ?

Comment: Because the added_date is not in group by clause. Try something like `order by max(b.added_date) desc limit 10`. Also, you select part is messed up. You shouldn't select `a.*` as you can't reliably tell which values out of the group will be picked.

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: SELECT a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.`filename`) AS `filesnames`,MAX(b.added_date)
FROM `school_classes` a
JOIN classes_data.`classes_albums` b ON a.`school_key` = b.`school_key`
    AND a.`class_key` = b.`class_key`
GROUP BY a.`ID` ORDER BY b.added_date DESC LIMIT 2

Comment: try this now ,i have added_date in select statement

Comment: #1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'b.added_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what your tables look like and how they relate but this might be what you are after.

```
drop table if exists school_classes;
   create table school_classes (id int,school_key int, class_key int);
   drop table if exists classes_albums;
   create table classes_albums(id int,school_key int, class_key int, filename varchar(3),dateadded date);

   insert into school_classes values
   (1,1,1), (2,1,2),(3,1,3)

   insert into classes_albums values
   (1,1,1,'a','2017-01-01'),(1,1,1,'b','2017-02-01'),(1,1,1,'c','2017-03-01');

    select a.*, b.filenames
    from school_classes a
    join
    (   
    select c.school_key,c.class_key,group_concat(c.filename order by c.rn desc) filenames
    from
    (
    select c.*,
            if(concat(c.school_key,c.class_key) <> @p, @rn:=1, @rn:=@rn+1) rn,
            @p:=concat(c.school_key,c.class_key) p 
    from classes_albums c, (select @rn:=0, @ck:=0,@sk:=0) rn
    order by c.school_key,c.class_key, c.dateadded desc
    ) c
    where c.rn < 3
    group by c.school_key,c.class_key
    ) b on b.school_key = a.school_key and b.class_key = a.class_key

+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id   | school_key | class_key | filenames |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |          1 |         1 | b,c       |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: the problem is the table that has file name it more 100 row i only want the latest 10 filenames CONCAT

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(b.`filename`)  LIMIT 10 something like that

Comment: Can you publish sample data (as text)?